# Override browser form-filling and input highlighting with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, input, autofill

I have 2 basic forms: sign in and sign up, both on the same page. Now, I have no problem with the sign in form auto-filling, <del>but the sign up form auto fills as well, and I don't like it.</del>

Also, the form styles get a yellow background which I can't manage to override and I don't want to use inline CSS to do so. What can I do to make them stop being colored yellow <del>and (possibly) auto filling</del>?

Comment: You're really asking two questions here: How to disable form autofill? -AND- How to override yellow background when form autofill is enabled? This wasn't clear until I read all the comments in the answers below. You might want to consider editing your question (especially since you've gone as far as to offer a bounty).

Comment: You're right, edited. Or a lazy version of it anyways.

Comment: As a user of the form, I'd hate to have my usability crippled because of your visual preferences by forcing auto complete and highlighting off. Let the user turn this off, not you. Leave my browsing experience alone.

Comment: That's the thing, I only disabled autocomplete in the REGISTRATION form, which basically, shouldn't have regular autocomplete, the completion info is only created once you've signed up. As for the login form, I want to keep autocomplete on, but just disable the dumb color it puts on the input fields because the text inside becomes unreadable -- the background is yellow and the text color is white (original background is dark gray).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background)

Comment: @zzzzBov check the dates, seems like your link is a duplicate of mine.

Comment: @OhMrBigshot, while duplicates typically are resolved in favor of the older question, there is also a tendency to resolve in favor of the question with more votes and or better answers. While yours is obviously a good question, the linked question has more votes (the people have spoken: images > words) and I feel that the answers are better.

Comment: That all said, I don't mind if you manage to get the other question closed as a duplicate of yours.

Comment: I really wish Google had chosen a less haggard colour than that yellow as the default background colour

Comment: http://codepen.io/richardos/pen/RoBdxv

Answer (score 183, accepted):

for the autocompletion, you can use:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

regarding the coloring-problem:

from your screenshot i can see that webkit generates the following style:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #FAFFBD !important;
}
```

1) as #id-styles are even more important than .class styles, the following *may* work:

```
#inputId:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

2) if that won't work, you can try to set the style via javascript programmatically

```
$("input[type='text']").bind('focus', function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});
```

**3) if that won't work, <strike>you're doomed :-)</strike> consider this:
this wont hide the yellow color, but will make the text readable again.**

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
        color: #2a2a2a !important; 
    }
```

**4) a css/javascript solution:**

css:

```
input:focus {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

and the following javascript has to be run onload:

```
function loadPage()
{
    if (document.login)//if the form login exists, focus:
    {
        document.login.name.focus();//the username input
        document.login.pass.focus();//the password input
        document.login.login.focus();//the login button (submitbutton)
    }
}
```

eg:

```
<body onload="loadPage();">
```

good luck :-)

5) If none of the above work try removing the input elements, cloning them, then placing the cloned elements back on the page (works on Safari 6.0.3):

```
<script>
function loadPage(){

    var e = document.getElementById('id_email');
    var ep = e.parentNode;
    ep.removeChild(e);
    var e2 = e.cloneNode();
    ep.appendChild(e2);

    var p = document.getElementById('id_password');
    var pp = p.parentNode;
    pp.removeChild(p);
    var p2 = p.cloneNode();
    pp.appendChild(p2);
}

document.body.onload = loadPage;
</script>
```

6) From [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543#c22):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).val();
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            $(this).after(this.outerHTML).remove();
            $('input[name=' + name + ']').val(text);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: (1) doesn't work. I'll try (2) when I get back home; hopefully JS can override this; thanks :)

Comment: (4) definitely removes yellow :focus border.

Comment: If the last bit does not work for you, and you do know how javascript works (got the Id's right etc.)

You could have the issue I had, I'm using jquery mobile for some reasons and this inits later and replaces the inputs it seems.
So what I did is set an interval which clones it every 50 ms (it worked after 400ms using setTimeout but I don't want to risk slow connections).
And after a second the interval is removed:
`code`

Comment: `var keepTheInputCloned = setInterval(function(){
            
            var e = document.getElementById('id_email');
            var ep = e.parentNode;
            ep.removeChild(e);
            var e2 = e.cloneNode();
            ep.appendChild(e2);

            var p = document.getElementById('id_password');
            var pp = p.parentNode;
            pp.removeChild(p);
            var p2 = p.cloneNode();
            pp.appendChild(p2);
        },50);
        setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(keepTheInputCloned)},1000);`

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with Safari on Mavericks. But when I employ method 5, they duke it out for one second (or three seconds when I set the timeout to 3000) and then the browser wins and I've got autocomplete turned on. In my usage case, I'm asking the user for their username/password for another site so that I can pull info from the other site, so I definitely don't want it autofilling the username and password they use for my site. Any thoughts on this (besides the doom of the original #3)?

Comment: what about using `.autofill-fix` ?

Answer (score 274):

**UPDATE: This doesn't work in the latest Chrome versions**

Trick it with a "strong" inside shadow:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px white inset; /* Change the color to your own background color */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
}

input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px white inset;/*your box-shadow*/
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
}
```

Comment: awesome this should be the number one answer, simple and effective

Comment: Very clever! Works well in Chrome.

Comment: doesn't work for background if i want to remove it (transparent)

Comment: This is the only way to change text color in Chrome (at least in version 43)

Comment: This is awesome in that it works and is really creative.  But it reminds me of old IE6 hacks and the like. Kinda crappy of google to give us a :-webkit-autofill parameter and not let designers override the default, right?

Comment: This yellow background is meant to help users **be aware** that these values are actually stored in the browser. You might not like it, but removing it while keeping the behavior is actually reducing usability and accessibility

Comment: Providing a color choice that cannot be customised isn't helping usability, nor accessibility. Those concerns are still entirely in the hands of the dev, except for this frustrating hack in Chrome. No-one can fault the intention of the Chrome devs, just the results.

Comment: Doesn't work in chrome 96.0 
The -internal-light-dark styling from chrome is overwriting everything. 
They even added  !important styling so you can't overwrite it! 
This makes no sense when we cannot programmatically change the user's light/dark preferences in the browser...

Comment: It DOES work in Chrome 115

Answer (score 30):

Add this CSS rule, and yellow background color will disapear. :)

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me - thanks! (though I needed to change white to the color I actually wanted)

Comment: Clearly the best answer.

Answer (score 26):

This seems to be working for me:

```css
input {
  -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution in case you want to have a transparent background

Comment: @Kerry7777 This is the only solution worked for me. And it's the simplest one. You made my day

Comment: Can confirm that this works. Using Next JS and tailwind css and specified this in my global.css @layer base

Answer (score 21):

After 2 hours of searching it seems Google Chrome still overrides the yellow color somehow, but I found the fix. It will work for hover, focus etc. as well. All you have to do is to add `!important` to it.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset !important;
}
```

this will completely remove yellow color from input fields

Comment: It works for me without the 1000px, just 0 everywhere,     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 white inset !important;

Answer (score 16):

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

Pretty much all modern browsers will respect that.

Comment: Awesome, but it only solves the less important issue; how can I keep auto complete but lose the style ( http://prntscr.com/4hkh ) webkit shoves down its throat? o: thanks though

Comment: Actually, it should do both.  The box only turns yellow to let you know that chrome/safari/ff has autofilled it with your password.  If you tell it not to fill, it won't get a chance to color it in.

Comment: yes, but look at what I said: "how can I **keep auto complete but lose the style** webkit shoves"

Comment: Only problem with `autocomplete` is that it’s invalid in HTML before version 5.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes autocomplete on the browser still autocompletes when you just have the code in the `<form>` element.

I tried putting it in the `<input>` element as well and it worked better.

```
<form autocomplete="off">  AND  <input autocomplete="off">
```

Support for this attribute however is ceasing, please read
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=956906#c1

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=956906

---

Another work around that I've found is taking out placeholders inside of the input fields that suggest that it is an email, username,  or phone field (ie. "Your Email", "Email", etc.")

[image]

This makes it so that browsers don't know what kind of field it is, thus doesn't try to autocomplete it.

Comment: What I like about this is most people WOULDN'T appreciate the whole form not being filled in on a page reload (e.g. a long text area), but allows the developer to prevent certain elements from being filled in (e.g. bank card number). Annoyingly though, support for this attribute is ceasing

Answer (score 3):

You can also change the name attribute of your form elements to be something generated so that the browser won't keep track of it. HOWEVER firefox 2.x+ and google chrome seems to not have much problems with that if the request url is identical. Try basically adding a salt request param and a salt field name for the sign-up form.

However I think autocomplete="off" is still top solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You can disable auto-completion as of HTML5 (via `autocomplete="off"`), but you CAN'T override the browser's highlighting. You could try messing with `::selection` in CSS (most browsers require a vendor prefix for that to work), but that probably won't help you either.

Unless the browser vendor specifically implemented a vendor-specific way of overriding it, you can't do anything about such styles that are already intended to override the site's stylesheet for the user. These are usually applied after your stylesheets are applied and ignore `! important` overrides, too.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to remove the autofill color with this approach:

```
  // Workaround to remove autofill color from inputs
  input, select {
    color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
    background-clip:  text !important;
  }
```

This is working for Safari and Chrome on iOS and Chrome on android, as far as I have tested.

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me in chrome

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer might have been a good answer for specific cases, but I was using angular material with transparent backgrounds and on top of that the <input> field was not the 'entre material field' with the fancy borders etc.

I made this modified solution, that just forces a very long transition on any of the autofill pseudo-elements, so that the change in properties is not even noticeable unless the user manages to stay on the same page for a considerable amount of the 1000000000 or so seconds that I have set it to!

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  transition: all 10000000s;
}
```

Comment: I've been working on this issue for about an entire afternoon in my NextJS project, and couldn't get a great solution. If I added the inset shadow hack and changed the text-fill color, I no longer had control of the text color before the auto-complete. If I used the background-clip hack, then I couldn't set the border I needed. All of the other workarounds left something undone.

This one works perfectly! You're simply delaying any of the effects the browser adds for the auto-complete styling, so you have complete control over the field styles. I lover this! Thank you so much for posting it!

Answer (score 3):

Just sharing [this great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44861998/2474466) from [wahmal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3188724/wahmal) for anyone who wants a transparent background for their input. Bypass all the annoying webkit default styling by adding a long delay to the transition from your default input styling to the webkit styling for autofill.

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
   -webkit-transition-delay: 9999s;
   transition-delay: 9999s;
}
```

Comment: Not working in Chrome 118.

Answer (score 2):

This fixes the problem on both Safari and Chrome

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("safari") >= 0){
window.setInterval(function(){
    $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){
        var clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
        $(this).after(clone).remove();
    });
}, 20);
}
```

Comment: I believe it will but wouldn't it be a bit harsh to do this 50 times each second? I know it'll work and won't be too slow. But seems a bit too much.

Answer (score 1):

The `form` element has an `autocomplete` attribute that you can set to `off`. As of the CSS the `!important` directive after a property keeps it from being overriden:

```
background-color: white !important;
```

Only IE6 doesn't understand it.

If I misunderstood you, there's also the `outline` property that you could find useful.

Comment: Chrome seems to ignore the !important when it autofills input-fields

Comment: @Torandi It might be because of the user-agent stylesheets. Settings from user-agent stylesheets should apply last, unless it has the `!important` directive, in which case it takes precedence over everything else. You should check out your user agent stylesheet (though I don't know where to find it).

Answer (score 1):

If it's in input field you're trying to "un-yellow" ...

1. Set a background-color with css... let's say #ccc (light gray).
2. Add value="sometext", which temporary fills the field with "sometext"
3. (optional) Add a little javascript to make the "sometext" clear when you go to put the real text in.

So, it might look like this:

```
<input id="login" style="background-color: #ccc;" value="username"
    onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='username';" 
    onfocus="if(this.value=='username') this.value='';" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets use a little css hack:

```
input:-webkit-autofill, 
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
textarea:-webkit-autofill, 
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
select:-webkit-autofill, 
select:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
select:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-internal-autofill-selected {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #000;
    background: #fff !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgb(255 255 255 / 0%), inset 0 0 0 100px #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:autofill` CSS pseudo-class is now available in modern browsers.  See [MDN :autofill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill)

However, as stated in the MDN page...

> Note: The user agent style sheets of many browsers use !important in their :-webkit-autofill style declarations, making them non-overridable by webpages without resorting to JavaScript hacks.

...and...

> This means that you cannot set the background-color, background-image, or color in your own rules.

So, still not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you linked to says that WebKit is using the selector `input:-webkit-autofill` for those elements. Have you tried putting this in your CSS?

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

If that doesn't work, then nothing probably will. Those fields are highlighted to alert the user that they have been autofilled with private information (such as the user's home address) and it could be argued that allowing a page to hide that is allowing a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Google toolbar's autocomplete feature disabled with javascript. It might work with some other autofill tools; I don't know if it'll help with browsers built in autocomplete.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
  if(window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload",setListeners);

  function setListeners(){
    inputList = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for(i=0;i<inputList.length;i++){
      inputList[i].attachEvent("onpropertychange",restoreStyles);
      inputList[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    selectList = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT");
    for(i=0;i<selectList.length;i++){
      selectList[i].attachEvent("onpropertychange",restoreStyles);
      selectList[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
  }

  function restoreStyles(){
    if(event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor != "")
      event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of things, I found working solutions that nuked the autofilled fields and replaced them with duplicated. Not to loose attached events, i came up with another (a bit lengthy) solution.

At each "input" event it swiftly attaches "change" events to all involved inputs. It tests if they have been autofilled. If yes, then dispatch a new text event that will trick the browser to think that the value has been changed by the user, thus allowing to remove the yellow background.

```
var initialFocusedElement = null
  , $inputs = $('input[type="text"]');

var removeAutofillStyle = function() {
  if($(this).is(':-webkit-autofill')) {
    var val = this.value;

    // Remove change event, we won't need it until next "input" event.
    $(this).off('change');

    // Dispatch a text event on the input field to trick the browser
    this.focus();
    event = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
    event.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, window, '*');
    this.dispatchEvent(event);

    // Now the value has an asterisk appended, so restore it to the original
    this.value = val;

    // Always turn focus back to the element that received 
    // input that caused autofill
    initialFocusedElement.focus();
  }
};

var onChange = function() {
  // Testing if element has been autofilled doesn't 
  // work directly on change event.
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    removeAutofillStyle.call(self);
  }, 1);
};

$inputs.on('input', function() {
  if(this === document.activeElement) {
    initialFocusedElement = this;

    // Autofilling will cause "change" event to be 
    // fired, so look for it
    $inputs.on('change', onChange);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple javascript solution for all browser:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".parent input").each(function(){
        parent = $(this).parents(".parent");
        $(this).clone().appendTo(parent);   
        $(this).attr("id","").attr("name","").hide();
    }); 
}, 300 );
```

Clone input, reset attribute and hide original input.
Timeout is needed for iPad

Answer (score 0):

Since the browser searches for password type fields, another workaround is to include a hidden field at the beginning of your form:

```
<!-- unused field to stop browsers from overriding form style -->
<input type='password' style = 'display:none' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've read so many threads and try so many pieces of code.
After gathering all that stuff, the only way I found to cleanly empty the login and password fields and reset their background to white was the following :

```
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('input:-webkit-autofill')
            .val('')
            .css('-webkit-box-shadow', '0 0 0px 1000px white inset')
            .attr('readonly', true)
            .removeAttr('readonly')
        ;
    }, 50);
});
```

Feel free to comment, I'm opened to all enhancements if you find some.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete off is not supported by modern browsers. The easiest way to solve autocomplete I found was a little track with HTML and JS.
The first thing to do is change the type of the input in HTML from 'password' to 'text'.

```
<input class="input input-xxl input-watery" type="text" name="password"/>
```

Autocomplete starts after window loaded. That's OK. But when the type of your field is not 'password', browser didn`t know what fields it must complete. So, there will be no autocomplete on form fields.

After that, bind event focusin to password field, for ex. in Backbone:

```
'focusin input[name=password]': 'onInputPasswordFocusIn',
```

In `onInputPasswordFocusIn`, just change the type of your field to password, by simple check:

```
if (e.currentTarget.value === '') {
    $(e.currentTarget).attr('type', 'password');
}
```

That`s it!

**UPD: this thing doesn't work with disabled JavaSciprt**

**UPD in 2018. Also found some funny trick. Set readonly attribute to the input field, and remove it on the focus event. First prevent browser from autofilling fields, second will allow to input data.**

Comment: Well autocomplete *is* part of the standard, though it's usage & implementation may vary. Also, changing input types in IE fails spectacularly, which is why jQuery blocks it, but generally it's not a good idea if you plan to support IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields

Comment: @casraf Sorry, it is a part of standart, but it don't work in all modern browsers as it must, so it will not do the thing it was invented for. In EDGE  it works fine, about previous versions can't tell anything(

Comment: True, it's not implemented everywhere. The problem still stands - depending on how far back you want to support IE - before v 11, I don't believe you can change the input type. If you're not worried about old versions, then you might as well use `autocomplete=off`, as it works in FF, Chrome for a while, and IE as of the previous version or so

Comment: I've tried to use autocomplete=off, both for inputs and form, and Chrome still fill signup and signin forms data(. This is just some kind of strange magic, because based on the comments, in some cases it works, and in some it does not =)

Comment: I know, these standards are not really being followed consistently. It's a shame, makes our lives harder :(

Comment: Yes, I thought that Safari < 9 and IE < 10 supporting will be enought pain for the developers, but things like this just makes me crazy!)

Answer (score 0):

I had to also change the text color to something darker (see StackOverflow dark theme colors).

So ended up with a hybrid of @Tamás Pap, @MCBL and @don's solution:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #2d2d2d inset !important;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #e7e8eb !important;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #e7e8eb !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style autofilled inputs using `:-webkit-autofill`

Even in firefox with the webkit-prefix!

To change the background color, there is the box-shadow trick.
And for Firefox you need additionally `filter:none`.

```css
:-webkit-autofill { 
    filter:none; /* needed for firefox! */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px rgba(38, 163, 48, 0.212) inset;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try with autocomplete="none" in your input tag

This works for me

Comment: Disabling "autocomplete" is not a good UX solution.

Comment: You also mean `autocomplete="off"`

Answer (score -3):

Why not just put this in your css:

```
input --webkit-autocomplete {
  color: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  border: inherit;
}
```

That should take care of your issue. Although it does raise a usability issue because now the user can't see that the form was autofilled in the way he/she is used to.

[edit] After posting this I saw that a similar answer was already given *and* that you commented on it that it didn't work. I don't quite see why because it did work when I tested it.

Comment: doesn't work in both chrome and safari. style is `input:-webkit-autofill` and `input --webkit-autocomplete` simply doesn't exist

Comment: @EliseuMonar: I'm pretty sure I wasn't lying, but can't remember details of how or where I tested it. The code itself was probably typed from memory, not copy/pasted, so autocomplete vs. autofill? I dunno.

Answer (score -3):

The REAL problem here is that Webkit (Safari, Chrome, ...) has a bug. When there's more than one [form] on the page, each with an [input type="text" name="foo" ...] (i.e. with the same value for the attribute 'name'), then when the user returns to the page the autofill will be done in the input field of the FIRST [form] on the page, not in the [form] that was sent. The second time, the NEXT [form] will be autofilled, and so on. Only [form] with an input text field with the SAME name will be affected.

This should be reported to the Webkit developers.

Opera autofills the right [form].

Firefox and IE doesn't autofill.

So, I say again: this is a bug in Webkit.