# Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, autofill

I have design problem with Google Chrome and its form autofill function.
If Chrome remembers some login/password it changes a background color to a yellow one.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

How to remove that background or just disable this autofill ?

Comment: I'd also like to see if there's an answer to this.

Comment: For styling, this colour can seriously with design elements, like the outlining in input tags in Chrome also, I would more like to change the colour than turn it off.

Comment: Google seems to acknowledge this issue to some degree. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543

Comment: @ANeves Well this is a major issue when you have an heavy design site where you use background or sprite methods to show the user what's is the desire value in a specify field. So if chrome override this background-image whith their background-color, Users wont see what you want to show them.

Comment: ANeves - the reason I need to disable autofill is because the user will be a manager who will use this page to add other users to the system, so the last thing he wants is for it to autofill the manager's username and password.  Also I'm finding that the Password box gets coloured, but the Retype Password box does not.

Comment: @ANeeves A concrete example of why I'm doing this (and why I'm here) is that the Chrome automatic styling when auto filling makes a background image disappear on the username / password input. When not auto filling, there is a User & Password icon inside each input. Not so 'beyond comprehension' :)

Comment: Rather than disabling the yellow background, just **don't use images** for your forms and it will look much better than that: http://i.imgur.com/DemnvGy.png

Comment: To disable autocomplete you can add **autocomplete="off"** to your input element, e.g. <input type="text" id="input" autocomplete="off">

Comment: Just an additional info: I was bitten by this when I have a password field. I got my fields highlighted automatically (yellow) and filled with strange value. 

And I found the solution here: http://www.zigpress.com/2014/11/22/stop-chrome-messing-forms/ ... The solution is in the section that says "Disable Google Chrome Autofill" ... add hidden fields.

Comment: Please check my workaround here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill/36030236#36030236

Comment: @hsz Please reconsider changing the marked answer, mine no longer applies and another answer is a far better solution.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

Change "white" to any color you want.

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset !important;
}
```

Comment: great idea. I wouldl stick with 50 or 100 whenever sufficent (regular size input boxes) to avoid potential performance hits on weaker devices. (And no need for px after 0)

Comment: Love this hack! Great thinking... Everyone is removing autofill. I wanted to keep autofill on just get ride of the ugly yellow.

Comment: Doesn't work if you have background images behind your input field just fill the whole area with white. I tried all the solutions on this page, including the jquery based ones and they didnt work for me, in the end i had to add autocomplete="off" to the field.

Comment: A good CSS-only compromise I guess. Please star the reported issue to encourage google devs to fix it https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543

Comment: Weird, this fixes the color...but now causes Chrome to auto-fill the username/password fields. No Google, I'm not logging in with my "create new user" form...

Comment: To also style the text color use `-webkit-text-fill-color` - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631943/change-font-color-of-autofill-input-field)

Comment: this removes the other jquery validations and CSS from the textbox :(

Comment: If you want to retain the original shadow using Bootstrap, you can use: `-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), inset 0 0 0 50px white;`

Comment: nice hack! none of other solutions worked for me.
i use this box shadow(nee less process):
  `-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 100px 0 white;`

Comment: This worked but I had to set the input:-webkit-autofill:focus class too.

Comment: there is error, i dont maybe syntax changed but this works now: `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px white !important;`

Comment: this is not a good solution because it also hides background images.

Comment: Yes good hack but unfortunately not working for transparent fields with background images...

Comment: what if i need the color to be transparent?

Comment: Does not play well if the field has multiple shadows applied. I have another inset shadow to get the effect of the field being cut out of my page, and in combination with this, the left and right side (with border radius) still becomes yellow. To test: Use a darker color than 'white'.

Comment: Good solution xD

Answer (score 53):

If you guys want transparent input fields you can use transition and transition delay.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 9999s;
    -webkit-transition: color 9999s ease-out, background-color 9999s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Best solution for me as RGBA color values did not work in `-webkit-box-shadow`. Also eliminates the need to give color values for this declaration: the default values will still apply.

Comment: even better is to use the transition delay instead of its duration, to not have color mixing at all

Comment: good but for some reason I had to move this rule at the end of the file, otherwise didn't worked

Comment: That what I looked for! Thank you!

Answer (score 43):

Solution [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543#c22):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).val();
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            $(this).after(this.outerHTML).remove();
            $('input[name=' + name + ']').val(text);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This did work whereas the top answer did not. However I think I will not try to change the behavior since a). this is javascript so there is a second between it works and it doesn't (until the js loads) and b). it may confuse the chrome user who is used to the default behavior.

Comment: My chrome just reapplies the yellow to the new input :(

Comment: Please don't. This will not work with any JS framework, only for static websites.

Answer (score 26):

In Firefox you can disable all autocomplete on a form by using the autocomplete="off/on" attribute.  Likewise individual items autocomplete can be set using the same attribute.

```
<form autocomplete="off" method=".." action="..">  
<input type="text" name="textboxname" autocomplete="off">
```

You can test this in Chrome as it should work.

Comment: Turning `autocomplete="off"` is not accessible these days.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution no longer works in Chrome.

Comment: This is highly disrecommended as you're not really solving the actual problem here. instead, you're creating a new one by frustrating users because they have to manually type their (presumably) login details (if they even remember what they were)

Answer (score 25):

If you want to preserve the autofill, as well as any data, attached handlers and functionality attached to your input elements, try this script:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0)
{
    var _interval = window.setInterval(function ()
    {
        var autofills = $('input:-webkit-autofill');
        if (autofills.length > 0)
        {
            window.clearInterval(_interval); // stop polling
            autofills.each(function()
            {
                var clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
                $(this).after(clone).remove();
            });
        }
    }, 20);
}
```

It polls until it finds any autofill elements, clones them including data and events, then inserts them into the DOM in the same location and removes the original. It stops polling once it finds any to clone since the autofill sometimes takes a second after page load. This is a variation of a previous code sample, but more robust and keeps as much functionality intact as possible.

(Confirmed working in Chrome, Firefox and IE 8.)

Comment: This was the only solution I found working, WITHOUT disabling autocomplete.

Comment: maybe setting intervals is not necessary as chrome autofills on window.load?

Comment: Works without removing auto complete, much better solution than the ones with millions of up votes.

Comment: The other solutions did not work for me, even the most upvoted one, but this one did. The problem, which is the opposite of what @Timo said above, is that Chrome does not autofill right at window.load. Even though this worked, one problem with it is that if there are no -webkit-autofill elements, the loop continuously runs. You don't even need an interval for this to work. Simply set a timeout with maybe a 50 millisecond delay and it will work fine.

Answer (score 16):

The following CSS removes the yellow background color and replaces it with a background color of your choosing.  It doesn't disable auto-fill and it requires no jQuery or Javascript hacks.

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px white inset; /* Change the color to your own background color */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
}
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: /*your box-shadow*/,0 0 0 50px white inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
}
```

Solution copied from:
[Override browser form-filling and input highlighting with HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css)

Comment: Does not play well if the field has multiple shadows applied.

Answer (score 6):

Worked for me, only the css change required.

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #ffffff inset!important;
}
```

you can put any color in place of **#ffffff**.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit hacky but works perfectly for me

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A combination of answers worked for me

```
<style>
    input:-webkit-autofill,
    input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
    input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
    input:-webkit-autofill:active {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #373e4a inset !important;
           -webkit-text-fill-color: white !important;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: This is the only example that worked for me with both text and background on Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 m

Answer (score 2):

Here's the MooTools version of Jason's. Fixes it in Safari too.

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() { 
    $('username').focus();

    if ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(\"chrome\") >= 0)||(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(\"safari\") >= 0))
    {

        var _interval = window.setInterval(function ()
        {
            var autofills = $$('input:-webkit-autofill');
            if (autofills.length > 0)
            {

                window.clearInterval(_interval); // stop polling
                autofills.each(function(el)
                {
                    var clone = el.clone(true,true).inject(el,'after');;
                    el.dispose();
                });
            }
        }, 20);                                               


    }
});
```

Comment: Don't use this script. If there are no autofilled elements, the loop will continuously run at 20 milliseconds. An interval is unnecessary. Set a timeout after window.load at around 50 milliseconds and that will be plenty of time to remove the styling.

Answer (score 2):

This fixes the problem on both Safari and Chrome

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("safari") >= 0){
window.setInterval(function(){
    $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){
        var clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
        $(this).after(clone).remove();
    });
}, 20);
}
```

Comment: Is what works for me. But the BUG still there, and as can be seen, no date to be fixed. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543#c22

Comment: You never clear your interval. This is sloppy code, don't use it.

Comment: Actually this doesnt work. I cant type anything in the inputs since they're constantly getting cloned. almost there...

Comment: try this
var id = window.setInterval(function(){
    $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){
        var clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
        $(this).after(clone).remove();
    });
}, 20);

$('input:-webkit-autofill').focus(function(){window.clearInterval(id);});

Answer (score 2):

This helped me, a CSS only version.

`input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}`

where *white* can be any color you want.

Answer (score 2):

I use this,

```
input:-webkit-autofill { -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset !important; }
input:focus:-webkit-autofill { -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset !important; }
/* You can use color:#color to change the color */
```

Answer (score 1):

In your  tag, simply insert this small line of code.

```
autocomplete="off"
```

However, do not place this in the username/email/idname field because if you are still looking to use autocomplete, it will disable it for this field. But I found a way around this, simply place the code in your password input tag because you never autocomplete passwords anyways. This fix should remove the color force, matinain autocomplete ability on your email/username field, and allows you to avoid bulky hacks like Jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of it entirely, I've adjusted the code in the previous answers so it works on hover, active and focus too:

```
input:-webkit-autofill, input:-webkit-autofill:hover, input:-webkit-autofill:active, input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset;
}
```

Comment: add a `!important` is necessary but thanks, its helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the yellow flicker until your css is applied slap a transition on that bad boy like so:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset !important;
    transition: background-color 10s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Mootools solution doing the same as Alessandro's - replaces each affected input with a new one.

```
if (Browser.chrome) {
    $$('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(item) {
        var text = item.value;
        var name = item.get('name');
        var newEl = new Element('input');
        newEl.set('name', name);
        newEl.value = text;
        newEl.replaces(item);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about that solution:

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    $(function() {
        var inputs = $('input:not(.auto-complete-on)');

        inputs.attr('autocomplete', 'off');

        setTimeout(function() {
            inputs.attr('autocomplete', 'on');
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

It turns off the auto-complete and auto-fill (so yellow backgrounds disappear), waits 100 milliseconds an then turns the auto-complete functionality back without auto-fill.

If you have inputs that need to be auto-filled, then give them `auto-complete-on` css class.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me, the username and password inputs were still being populated and given the yellow background.

So I asked myself, "How does Chrome determine what should be autofilled on a given page?"

"Does it look for input ids, input names? Form ids? Form action?"

Through my experimentation with the username and the password inputs, there were only two ways I found that would cause Chrome to not be able to find the fields that should be autofilled:

1) Put the password input ahead of the text input.
2) Give them the same name and id ... or no name and id.

After the page loads, with javascript you can either change the order of the inputs on the page, or dynamically give them their name and id ...

And Chrome doesn't know what hit it ... autocomplete stays off.

Crazy hack, I know. But it's working for me.

Chrome 34.0.1847.116, OSX 10.7.5

Answer (score 0):

The only way that works for me was:(jQuery required)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    if ($.browser.webkit) {
        $('#input_id').val(' ').val('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue for a password field i have like this:

Set the input type to text instead of password

Remove the input text value with jQuery

Convert the input type to password with jQuery

```
<input type="text" class="remove-autofill">

$('.js-remove-autofill').val('');    
$('.js-remove-autofill').attr('type', 'password');
```

Comment: Does not work in Chrome. As soon as the field becomes type=password, Chrome fills it in

Answer (score 0):

An update to Arjans solution. When trying to change the values it wouldnt let you. This works fine for me. When you focus on an input then it will go yellow. its close enough.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("safari") >= 0){
        var id = window.setInterval(function(){
            $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){
                var clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
                $(this).after(clone).remove();
            });
        }, 20);

        $('input:-webkit-autofill').focus(function(){window.clearInterval(id);});
    }
});

$('input:-webkit-autofill').focus(function(){window.clearInterval(id);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
  $(function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
      $('[name=user_password]').attr('type', 'password');
     }, 1000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="user_password" type="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

*fareed namrouti* answer is correct. But the background still get yellow when **the input is selected**. Adding `!important` fix the problem. If you want also `textarea` and `select` with the same behavior just add `textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill`

**Only input**

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189) !important;
}
```

**input, select, textarea**

```
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `autocomplete="off"` is not gonna cut it.

Change input type attribute to `type="search"`.
Google doesn't apply auto-fill to inputs with a type of search.

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked in my case:

```
:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #000; /* ok for text, no hack */
  transition-property: background-color; /* begin hack for background... */
  transition-delay: 100000s; /* ...end hack for background */
}
```

This solution is not ideal, it is while waiting to find better ...

Answer (score -1):

The final solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contadorInterval = 0;
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0)
    {
        var _interval = window.setInterval(function ()
        {
            var autofills = $('input:-webkit-autofill');
            if (autofills.length > 0)
            {
                window.clearInterval(_interval); // stop polling
                autofills.each(function()
                {
                    var clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
                    $(this).after(clone).remove();
                    setTimeout(function(){
//                        $("#User").val('');
                        $("#Password").val('');
                    },10);
                });
            }
            contadorInterval++;
            if(contadorInterval > 50) window.clearInterval(_interval); // stop polling
        }, 20);
    }else{
        setTimeout(function(){
//            $("#User").val('');
            $("#Password").val('');
        },100);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```

Similar Question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: chrome ignores the autocomplete="off"

Comment: Disable Autocomplete in Google Chrome: <a href="http://browsers.about.com/od/googlechrome/ss/google-chrome-form-autofill.htm">Link</a>

Answer (score -5):

Just found myself with the same question.  This works for me:

```
form :focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: thats the outline on the box when you click in it, not the autofilled input's background colour