# Change font color of autofill input field

Tags: html, css

I've managed to change the background color of an autofilled input field from yellow to white with the following code:

```
input.login:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset;
}
```

However, changing the font color to grey simply by adding `color: #999;` doesn't work. How could I fix this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try the below **CSS**

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px white inset; /* Change the color to your own background color */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #999;
}
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: /*your box-shadow*/,0 0 0 50px white inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #999;
}
```

Comment: this code works but only for mozila. How can we do this for chrome..??

Answer (score 17):

Try the below CSS:

```
/* Change Autocomplete styles in Chrome*/
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus
input:-webkit-autofill, 
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

We can use the `-webkit-autofill` pseudo-selector to target those fields and style them as we see fit.

Comment: This is the most complete answer I have seen that solves this problem. Thank you!

Comment: This deserves to be the checked answer. Worked fine!

Answer (score -3):

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    color: #999 !important;
}
```

This would work for you!

Comment: You didn't even do it correctly.... Also no, don't use `!important`. **Note:** It's like this - `color: #999 !important;`

Comment: @Ruddy:Thanks,I have updated my answer. Could you please tell me, why we should not use important? I'm not much familiar with css, but I knw the answer, so replied.

Comment: Take a look at this [**page**](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/). Its a good little read. For this I don't feel there is a need to use `!important` just feels lazy when there are another ways to do it.

Comment: @Ruddy: Thanks, quite useful for me :)