# Input (text) bg color if text is selected from suggestions?

Tags: css, html

```
<input type="text">
```

If I have a textbox using the code above,  enter text into it, move on and come back to the textbox later, then delete the text, it will show the previously entered text as a suggestion. If I click the suggestion, it changes the background color of the entire textbox. 
How do I either make it not do that or change the color that it changes it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to turn off autocomplete simply add this to your input field

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

this way you'll be free of it, but to change the color take a look at this links [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete) and [Change font color of autofill input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631943/change-font-color-of-autofill-input-field) they'll definitely be of help