# Best way to add validation ticks/cross in checkout /w autocomplete

Tags: checkout, css, forms, validation

What is: the Best way to add validation ticks/cross in checkout /w autocomplete

We are looking to add those green check marks or ticks to checkout fornfields when data entry is valid.

- we add validation class to the form
- add observer that calls validation.validate
  (And validation.validate adds CSS class)
- then we set CSS background for validation-passed class to green tick image in background

This works fine ... Until we turn in autocomplete. In google chrome the yellow background auto fill overrides any background.

So now what?
- use CSS::after?
- use jquery after to add span class?
- try to outsmart google chrome

Any experiences to share on programming green ticks and red crosses on checkout form template?

Help appreciated

Comment: I doubt this can be fixed.  Chrome's yellow background is infamous, it cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background)

```
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset;
}
```

You may need to add 3 variations (normal - on site load, validation pass and validation fail)