# Change form autofill background yellow color

Tags: jquery, css, forms, google-chrome, autofill

I found this topic [Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background)

I have the same problem but for some reason the solution doesn't work in the website that I develop.

I am new to jQuery so I would really appreciate some help.

The website is at http://anaxshipping.com/cms/demo2/

For instance instead of the yello background i would like a trasparent.

I have changed the $ to jQuery but nothing changed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here Is The Described Solution Of Your Question [Remove forced yellow input background in Chrome](http://labs.enonic.com/articles/remove-forced-yellow-input-background-in-chrome)

Comment: Hi thanks for the article!

I am having a diffrent problem if someone can help. 

The same module in Mozilla has a bug. It doesn't display "enter your email" here.

I checked my CSS I can't find why exactly is that. In chrome is ok. Any ideas?