# Make yellow autocomplete transparent in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, webkit

This is the textarea

[image: http://i.imgur.com/kdugksf.png]

This is the textarea that is clicked on and has text in it

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jKo4WrG.png]

When Google chrome's autocomplete hijacks the textarea

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ex8fYyu.png]

I've tried fixing it by putting in this code

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #FFFFFF inset;
}
```

But the best I can get it to look like is this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/XyPNLZz.png]

I want the white box to either be transparent, or it can stay white but be smaller so that it does not block any of the blue parts of the textbox. Is this possible at all? I've tried googling around and I came up with nothing. Or if you guys have any other ideas on how to fix this, that would be great!

Also, if there is a way to make the autocomplete box just a little bit smaller that would be fine too, or maybe a way to move the label down ? =/

**I want autocomplete on.**

Comment: did you try `backgound-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)` for the autocomplete?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: @j_s_stack OP of course.

Comment: or `background:transparent;`

Comment: @imtheman I'm not sure what you want a code snippet of?

Comment: @j_s_stack that just makes it go to the default yellow auto complete

Comment: @www139 That just makes it the default yellow auto complete

Comment: Try looking at the style of the element when it is yellow and look at what css property is making it yellow. Than take the appropriate measures.

Comment: @www139 http://i.imgur.com/ilzDTRL.png

Comment: Try adding !important

Comment: @www139 Where would I add it?

Comment: like this: `background-color: #fff !important;`

Comment: have you figured it out? Did my updated answer not work? Is there anything else I can do to help?

Comment: Can we see the code?

Answer (score -1):

try this: `background-color: #fff !important;`

http://labs.enonic.com/articles/remove-forced-yellow-input-background-in-chrome

[Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Are you sure I found this: [Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background)

Comment: input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
Does not do anything.

Comment: Are you sure you have the selector correct?

Comment: Are you sure I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Comment: http://labs.enonic.com/articles/remove-forced-yellow-input-background-in-chrome

Comment: Look at those links. They talk about your problem.

Comment: this answer is not correct

Answer (score -3):

Please try this:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

rgba fourth argument is opacity level.

Comment: Goes to the default yellow autocomplete

Answer (score -3):

also try:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
   background:rgba(255,255,255,0) !important;
}
```