# Cannot set white background to HTML input in Mozilla

Tags: html, css, input

A strange behavior prevents me from setting white color for an HTML input element's background color (background property) in Mozilla Firefox (it switches to a yellow color). Other colors works fine (black, green). Does anybody know why?
[image]

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #A6A6A633;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  background: white;
  color: #9B9B9B;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="username">User Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="username" [(ngModel)]="username" placeholder="Enter User Name" name="username">
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Since it turned out the problem is caused by Mozilla's autocomplete, it's not a problem anymore since in normal use it changes the background as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the yellow background on input on autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120333/remove-the-yellow-background-on-input-on-autofill)

Comment: -moz-appearance: ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the background in perfectly white. I think, there is some other code, that affects your input. Try to make it more specific using the ID **#username**.

Or, you can use !important rule.

**UPDATED**

Added the third way. It may be an autocomplete background of browther. Try the code below.

```css
input#username {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #A6A6A633;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  background: #fff !important;
  color: #9B9B9B;
}

input#username:-moz-autofill,
input#username:-moz-autofill-preview,
input#username:-webkit-autofill {
  filter: none;
  background: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="username">User Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="username" [(ngModel)]="username" placeholder="Enter User Name" name="username">
</div>
```

Comment: Either way it doesn;t work in Mozilla, just on Chrome.

Comment: Ho i see. It's autocomplete color of the Firefox. Add some code for you.

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue using the Mozilla specific tags but it's also not a problem anymore, since it's just autocomplete and without it it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

> the code listed bellow is not necessary as mentioned in the comments. however refreshing cache helped as the problem came of autocomplete.

### OLD

**Use `background-color: white;`** and not `Background: white;`

```
    input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #A6A6A633;
border-radius: 2px;
opacity: 1;
background-color: white;
    color: #9B9B9B;
  }
```

Comment: Apparently doesn't work in Mozilla FIrefox, only on Chrome. It must be some special property to this browser.

Comment: @BR4TO92 have you reset the cache?

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. I opened the page in private mode and now the background is white. Edit your answer so I can approve it. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter. `background: white` is just shorthand for `background-color: white`.

Comment: @BR4TO92 That's a red herring. Private mode turns off autofill.

Comment: Actually the autocomplete is the actual answer.

Comment: @BR4TO92 aaah, hahah i see, that is a hard one to catch, i have updated once again