# White background when selecting suggested option in angular material input

Tags: css, angular, input, angular-material, angular-forms

Hello fellow developers!

I noticed this issue a long time ago and still don't even know how to google it.
The problem is the following:
When typing in angular input I have options popping up - all of them are the values that I ever entered to this or any other input, upon hover on one of the suggested items the background of the text becomes white, same happens if I choose one of the options.
[image]

[image]

But if I type the same value manually (or any other original value), then everything is perfectly fine:

[image]

Not sure if the problem is with Angular Material here. I am using MacBook for development, if it helps.
I will be happy if anyone can shine the light on this issue!

Cheers!

Comment: I believe this is something that browser do. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29120510/1440005) and the question as well, maybe you figure something out.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Hey, thanks for the lead! That answer led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete]), and I managed to get the result I wanted:)