# styling form fields, issue with Chrome

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome

The following trivial (but annoying) issue occurs only with Chrome. Firefox and IE do not exhibit the problem.  I am using the latest version of each.  I haven't checked Safari yet.

While testing a form, I have noticed that when data is entered that has been entered before, the background color of the field changes colors.

**EXAMPLE:**

I have two text fields: **first_name** and **last_name**.  I enter Bill and Jones and submit the form.  Everything is great.

Now, I go back and enter Bill and Smith.  This is where the issue arrises.

Because I had already entered Bill in **first_name**, Chrome changes the background color of **first_name** to an ugly yellow color, over-riding the light gray that I want.

However, **last-name** does not do this because I entered a different last name.  As long as the data has not previously been entered, the background color stays gray.  If it has been previously entered, ugly yellow.

As I mentioned above, this does not occur in IE or Firefox.

I have tested it on multiple installations of Chrome, and the problem is always duplicated.  So it is definitely a Chrome issue.

Also, this only occurs on some TEXT fields. I have a SELECT field that does not cause the problem.  I also have another TEXT field that accepts a date from jQuery datepicker.  This, too, does not cause the problem.

One last thing that may be useful. The code shown below is what I am currently using.  If I add **autocomplete="off"**, this fixes the problem.  But I want autocomplete="on".

```
<input class="input_textfield" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required />
```

So, does anyone know how to fix this with CSS?  Or am I stuck with the ugly yellow?  I've tried searching for an answer, but I am not sure if I am asking the right question.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This answer seems to address the question you're having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background

Comment: Thank you, Felipe.   Yes, this does address the problem.  Very frustrating - I searched for quite some time and did not run across this response.