# Make autocomplete input transparent in google chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

Before reading, note THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE, why ? Because the answer never had the GOOD answer, the answer we need.

So, what we basically want to do, is make a input transparent, like this:

[image: A example of transparent background in a input]

This is beautiful, right ? Well, now look at that :

[image: A not beautiful input at all]

That just look... horrible.
Is there any way around this ?

The following thing does NOT work :

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #EEEEEE !important;
}
```

An idea ?

Comment: background-color: transparent, could you make a fiddle

Comment: Sorry, those things don't work inside a browser-specific selector

Comment: I like the solution in this question by Jason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background

Answer (score 0):

That's the webkit autofill

```
 input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px white inset; 
}
```

change the white to whatever you want.

Also - if you want to change the text color it's :

```
 -webkit-text-fill-color: yourColor !important;
```

If you do not want to use this solution, you can use something like this

```
input {
    background-color: red !important;
 }
```

See here for full information - http://labs.enonic.com/articles/remove-forced-yellow-input-background-in-chrome

But mostly the suggestion is to use

```
 input:-webkit-autofill {
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px white inset; 
 }
```

Comment: Hello, i am not marking this question as OK since it does not make the input transparent :)

Comment: @TijlVandenBrugghen input:-webkit-autofill {  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) !important; }