# Chrome's autofill hiding text input's background image

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, user-agent

After successfuly disabling the autofill's yellowish background-color,
I stumbled upon another feature.

Each of my input elements have a background image, and every time I focus on a text input, the browser suggests values I used before in a drop down list.

After I pick a value, the autofill covers my entire background and hides the image.

Here's my html and css (elaborated in JSfiddle):

```
<section class="formContainer">
    <img class="sesameLogo" src="~/Content/Images/Site/sesamelogo.png" />
    <form id="signUpForm" class="pageForm">
        <input type="text" name="decoy" class="decoy"/>
        <input type="password" name="decoy" class="decoy" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="FullName" id="fullName" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmPassword" id="secPassword" />
        <section id="actionBtnsCont">
            <button id="btnSignUp" class="mainBtn" type="button">Sign Up</button>
            <label class="genContextLbl">or</label>
            <button id="btnSignIn" class="genBtn" type="button">Sign In</button>
        </section>
    </form>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/65wkgqs0/

Comment: link shows just a blank new project

Comment: I noticed, fixed. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background)

Comment: It's not.. I've seen that thread and it helped me lose the yellow background, my issue is that its covering my background image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is:

move background image from `<input>` element

**HTML**

```
<div class="email-wrapper">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.email-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://www.apec-econ.ca/system/style/images/icon-small-person.png) no-repeat scroll 4px 9px;
}
```

and postpone changing of background-color when autofill

**CSS**

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/65wkgqs0/6/

Comment: Thanks, works great! Although, I wish I could find another way to do it other than animation or concatenating two elements..

Comment: This is not working for me. Background image continues to disappear.

Comment: This seems to put the background image behind the input