# Bold Autofill in Recent Chrome Update

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, autofill

Following the most recent Chrome update, the autofill options (as shown below) are all in bold. This is not website-specific, meaning it happens on all websites.

Is there a way to prevent the autofill options from being **bold**?

[image]

Comment: Hmmm...interesting. Not sure that's something that can be styled.

Comment: First they added the yellow background to the autofill, now the bold text...

Comment: Yeah but it's not a DOM object, it'd browser generated. Maybe a broswer setting?

Comment: @Paulie_D Hmm.. I'll look if it is a setting in the browser. Other users reported this issue too: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Lp0NyHBMXsM;context-place=forum/chrome

Comment: same here with chrome 50.0.2661.94 m

Comment: Yeah....I'm assuming it was a request from users but it does seem arbitrary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background

Comment: Same here with version 50.0.2661.94

Comment: I noticed this in Opera's last update, then after Chrome updated it was like that as well. Is Chrome just copying Opera or is there any real purpose to this?