# How can we overwrite user agent stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a form where i saved my login credentials. Now chrome is showing its own background color to the input fields. 
I did research for this but didn't found anything. 
**Is there any way to overwrite user agent stylesheet which is coming from chrome only with css?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can change the styles like so:

```
/* Change Autocomplete styles in Chrome*/
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus
input:-webkit-autofill, 
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Follow the article for more info:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/