# Change autocomplete background color on google chrome in css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Yes, there's a lot of questions about this, but none of them seems to work with me.

I need to change the autocomplete background color on google chrome:

[image]

[image]

I already tried all of this:

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

[Solution 3](http://webagility.com/posts/remove-forced-yellow-input-background-in-chrome)

This is my css:

`input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px black inset;
}`

And this is my cshtml:

```html
 <div class="row m-t-50">
       <div class="input-field col s12">
           <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate" asp-for="Username">
           <label for="last_name">Usuário</label>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code should be working and appropriate. In my mind, there could be two possible reasons of seeing not any changes in your css class:

1- One scenario that happened to me a number of times is when Chrome does not apply defined css styles to the page properly and the only solution I've found to this problem is to restart the computer.

2- If you are using a css library such as Bootstrap or MDL, ensure that they do not have predefined identical definition. I have never checked it out. However, by using the Chrome Developer Tools, you may figure it out:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap css library and yes, it have predefined identical definition. Just changed what I needed and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much! Save my day!