# Random style appearing in an input element. Where is it coming from?

Tags: html, css

I have a form input element:

`<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" size="25" autocomplete="off" required>`

I am styling it as such:

```
.form-control {
  background-color: #010101;

  &:-internal-autofill-selected {
    background-color: #010101 !important;
  }
}
```

But for some reason I'm getting a white RGB color appearing instead of the black background.

When I inspect the element I see the below:

[image]

When I click the color style to view wherer it is set it just shows me my CSS above with the dark background color.

Would anyone know where this colour is coming from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is Google Chrome <input /> Auto fill background color changed in Version 72.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941772/is-google-chrome-input-auto-fill-background-color-changed-in-version-72-0)

Comment: it's right there in your inspector `input:-internal-autofill-selected`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid "-internal-autofill-selected" style to be applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083813/how-to-avoid-internal-autofill-selected-style-to-be-applied)

Comment: probably a better dupe target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Comment: @billynoah no luck implementing those solutions sorry

Comment: just because those solutions don't work for you (or no longer work in current browser) doesn't mean it's not a dupe question. if you still think it's not, please add an MCVE, your browser, os, versions, etc, so we can see the difference.