# Set background color of autocomplete on a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have create a chrome extension to autocomplete forms.

The code I'm using to autocomplete is basically the once from [this site](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

It does its job, but I'm having issues to read the suggestion because the background is transparent as shown in the below image:

[image]

Is it possible from the extension to set a solid white background color?

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to change it as suggested. This changes work:

```
document.querySelector("[id='tags']").style.color="Red"
document.querySelector("[id='tags']").style.backgroundColor="Red"
```

But that only changes the text box:

[image]

And I want to chang the background on the options only.

I tried this one:

```
document.querySelector("[id='tags']").background-color =  "Red"
```

And got the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Comment: I don't know that plugin but for the standard Chrome'a autocomplete it's different, see [Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2920306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the website you have referenced adds `<ul>` when showing autocomplete. You need to add a css for `ul` to have a `background-color`. So the following code works for me.

```
  ul#ui-id-1 {
   background-color: red;
  }
```

Comment: Where in the code will go that part? is it inside the JS function?

Comment: you can add a css file with the css code and it should work. I havent used jqueryui. I'm just giving you from the common javascript background

Comment: I tried to do it with JS, that part in not working for me, I just updated the question with the results I got

Comment: if you want to target id then you can target the `ul` id which is `ui-id-1` so your code will look something like this `document.getElementById('ui-id-1').style.backgroundColor = 'red'`