# Remove Web-kit input background

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, input, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background)

Is possible to remove the `web-kit` yellow and really bad `background` from the `input` elements?

See the image[image]

I tried with simple `background:#fff;` but it doesn't work.

This doesn't work:

```
input[type="text"],input[type="password"],textarea{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    min-height:30px;
    padding:1%;
    background: #fff !important;
  }
```

I am on Mac OSX with Chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/J6Y9s/2/

The only solution I've found is  this code that is working with jQuery, but i don't want to remove the comfortable autocomplete from the inputs :

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    $('input[name="password"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
}
```

Comment: from where this background came from? It is not default

Comment: Which browser are you using? If in Chrome, right-click on the yellow bit and choose Inspect Element. On the right side, you should see any css affecting it and the selectors and file names where its being set from.

Comment: for me it is default, maybe when browser remember your data .. cause i have 3 fields 1 is white background the other are yellowed, and the one with white background is the only one has no pre-setted data inside

Comment: Also, can you share the url where you're seeing this?

Comment: oops sorry .. check this out now

Comment: Then you need to setup a jsfiddle that replicates this so we can see.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2338102/733347

Comment: @Mr.Alien cause you don't have autofill i think :/

Comment: Working on triggering autofill on my end.

Comment: @Geuis so strange .. are you on macosx?

Comment: Ive got it triggered. I'm researching a solution. Of note, read the last couple comments on this bug. This is on someone's radar at chromium to fix, but its already been around for 4 years. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543

Comment: @Geuis omg you're right, then i tested the NullPointer code below and it works, sure, but onyl at first page refresh!! incredible!

Comment: lspuk, check out my answer below. I am pretty sure this is as close as we can get to what you want until/unless Google fixes the bug I linked to before. Good luck, this took 5 cigarettes and 90% of a fifth of scotch to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holy Cow! This seems to work finally. There is one caveat, in which there is still a flash of yellow before the new DOM elements are added in. This appears to be **completely unavoidable**. Thanks to NullPointer for having the initial concept, though the implementation didn't quite work as originally posted.

http://jsfiddle.net/a6Pqy/

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="frm">
    First name:<input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" /><br />
    Address: <input type="text" name="address" /><br />
</form>​
```

JS:

```
//This is one hackish piece of code. Please encourage the Chromium group to FIX THIS BUG http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0) {

    //must clear the contents of the element on focus or the Chrome autocomplete monstrosity doesn't respond to the 'input'event since it may already have pre-populated content from before.
    $(document).on('focus', '#frm > input', function(){
       $(this).val(''); 
    });

    //listen for the input event, meaning autocomplete may have occurred
    $(document).on('input', '#frm > input', function(){

         //setTimeout is critical because it delays the rendering engine by a frame so that the following selector grabs all valid -webkit-autofill inputs            
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){

                var val = $(this).val(),
                    attributes = $(this)[0].attributes,
                    el = $('<input>');

                //we make an entirely new element and copy all of the old attributes to it. jQuery doesn't offer a native way to do this.
                for(var i=0; i<attributes.length; i++){
                     el[0].setAttribute( attributes[i].nodeName, attributes[i].nodeValue );
                }
                //set the autocompleted value to the new element
                el.val( val );

                //insert the new element then remove the old one.
                $(this).after(el).remove();

            });

        },0);

    });

}
```

Comment: That is horribly hacky but I've found no other way so here is your plus one.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the below and that solved the my problem (remove yellow color ) so i hope this is also helpful for you

i have tried the css

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    color: #f5f5f5!important;
}
```

i have also tried the jquery and both were working

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).val();
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            $(this).after(this.outerHTML).remove();
            $('input[name=' + name + ']').val(text);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You're trying to answer a question to which he has provided few details so far. Its like stabbing in the dark.

Comment: @Geuis but i think my answer provide the solution

Comment: Since I know this behavior is not a default in Chrome, there is some stylesheet or js that is causing it. Without seeing actual code, we cannot hope to give an accurate nor honest answer.

Comment: @Geuis cool .... i trued this in my website and its the working one .. so  i thought that its helpful for the OP ...

Comment: NP, do a minor edit on your answer so I can remove the downvote =)

Comment: hey guys here seems me i am the one is downvoting, really i downvoted 1 person only who told me to remove the autocmplete then didn't taouched votes :/

Comment: @Geuis is that ok.... ??

Comment: @Ispuk is my answer is working for you .. since it was working for me

Comment: for me nope i tryed deleting cache too, need to check boostrap css sec

Comment: then ..... navigator was not HTML5!?

Comment: @Ispuk cool than i am gonna delete my answer ...

Comment: :D then sorry why color: instead of background: can you please document better the answer @NullPointer

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is possible. You could try putting `!important` after the color declaration but I unfortunately don't have a web-kit browser here that I can test on.

Answer (score -1):

You need to turn off autocomplete for this field:

```
<input name="password" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

If you want use autocomplete and always use custom background color for the input it's unfortunately impossible. Here is an issue about that in the Chromium tracker http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543.

Comment: but i want the autocomplete :/

Comment: meeeee??? i just added 1 downvote me is not is downvoting :/

Comment: i tryed and it works removing autocmplete but i don't like to remove user presetted data :(

Comment: check i edited my question @bjornd