# Is there a tool to examine HTML page without clicking?

Tags: html, google-chrome

My problem is this - when I click the down button on any input control on my form **in Chrome** a popup window is displayed. I am positive my code does not do it. The fact that it happens only in Chrome makes me think of some misbehaving Chrome plugin/extension.

Anyway, I would like to see the HTML element responsible for this popup. However, I cannot find it in the dev tools and trying to focus on it does not work - the popup closes the moment I click the page.

So, my question - is there a **easy** way to get hold on this HTML element without clicking the page?

[image]

I am using Chrome 23.0.1271.64 with the following extensions (according to the Chrome itself):

- Advanced REST client 3.0.30
- JSONView 0.0.32
- OneClickDownload 1.2 Web
- Developer 0.4.1

Comment: Has this got something to do with the issue. http://browsers.about.com/od/googlechrome/ss/google-chrome-form-autofill.htm
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/2416597/903454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks just like the standard input field suggestion box. I suspect it is not part of the web page. Therefore it won't appear in the DOM and you can't style it, because it is part of the browser not the web page (although it appears over the top of the web page).

You can suppress it by putting the attribute & value autocomplete=off on the form field, although that is from HTML5 and will not work in all browsers just yet. See [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582244/is-there-a-w3c-valid-way-to-disable-autocomplete-in-a-html-form)

Comment: Yes, this is definitely such a suggestion box. I think meanwhile most major browsers should unterstand autocomplete=off, at least those who implement it, like Google Chrome.