# How to turn off the autocomplete function on browsers

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, safari

This has been bugging me for a while and i was wondering how to prevent it in code.
I am using safari to test my code and i have lots of forms, when i type in something that starts with the same letters, safari puts up this stupid bar. I was wondering if that is possible to prevent.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried looking into the HTML reference of your choice about that?

Comment: Or perhaps into the manual of the Safari browser you're concerned about?

Comment: According to your accepted answer, you might be interested in: [Override browser form-filling and input highlighting with HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2338102/367456) and [Is there a W3C valid way to disable autocomplete in a HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/582244/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this attribute to your input field:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this in your forms:

`autocomplete="off"` this should fix the issue for all modern browsers.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off"
   action="http://www.example.com/form.cgi">
  [...]
</form>
```

In current versions of Gecko browsers, the autocomplete attribute works perfectly. For earlier versions, going back to Netscape 6.2, it worked with the exception for forms with "Address" and "Name"

[Documetation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion#How_to_Turn_Off_the_Autocompletion_Feature)

Answer (score 0):

In Safari, go to Preferences > AutoFill and uncheck Other Forms.

Comment: -1. The question clearly asks "how to prevent it in code", and "go to Preferences->AutoFill" is not preventing it "in code".

Comment: Pretty sure the original question didn't mention code...

Comment: I'm [pretty sure](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18678650/1) it did.