# Chrome autocomplete input style

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, input

Is there a way to custom style/remove the yellow autofill `background-color` that Google Chrome add to input boxes with `autocomplete="on"`?

I found some solution out there, but they all remove the autocomplete feature or add an inset shadow to cover the yellow.

But i need to retain the autocomplete feature and use a custom background (linear-gradient) for the input.

Edit: I tried to override the stylesheet, but it isn't working, it might be a Chrome bug?

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override browser form-filling and input highlighting with HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css)

Comment: Yes, don't use inputs.. use div's styled and used like inputs

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;}
```