# Getting rid of webkit user-agent stylesheet rules?

Tags: css, macos, safari, webkit

i've a problem with webkit user agent stylesheet.

here's the css i'm trying to override:

> input:-webkit-autofill — user agent stylesheet
>
> background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189) !important; background-image:
>   none !important; color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;

here's mine

> input:-webkit-autofill background-color: rgba(250, 255, 189,
>   0.5)!important;
>   color: #000!important;

**here's the fiddle jsfiddle.net/Rx27s**

i need it to avoid the **"background-image:none on my login"**

thanks in advance for all

Comment: Are you using that exact CSS code? It cannot work, since it lacks the `{` and `}` delimiters.

Comment: you want background image for your input?

Comment: hi guys! thanks for your time.

that's my actual code:

input[type="password"]{background: url("../graphics/img/password.png") no-repeat!important; background-position:3px 3px!important;}

input[type="password"]:hover{background-color:#4fa9a1!important;}

input[type="password"]:focus{background-color:#4fa9a1!important;}

input:-webkit-autofill {background-color: rgba(250, 255, 189, 0.5) !important; color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;}

Comment: i've a background image already, but with webkit autofill remove it. :(

Comment: can you reproduce your problem in fiddle??

Comment: here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rx27s/

Comment: but that's a login form. safari will not autocomplete there

Comment: Maybe duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css