# -webkit-autofill overwrite issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, less

I am trying to remove/overwrite the style that chromes apply to inputs fields with form autocomplete="on".

My code is (using less for all css):

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px @black inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: @light-text-shadow;
}
```

And its working, but still i got issue with the border. `-webkit-box-shadow` only fills inside the input element, i still get a strange border around the element. Even with my own custom border set.
I tried to include the same custom border code inside this rule, but no changes. Only happens after input get the content throw autocomplete/select.

Anyone can help me resolve this?

Comment: I expect that your are missing the `:focus` pseudo class seletor. try: `input:-webkit-autofill,input:-webkit-autofill:focus` as described here at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13860010/1596547