# Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete for login only

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, laravel

I have a specific background that uses an image but chrome messes it up and I don't want to replace all the forms with the solution

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

So is there some way around it less generalized and more precise than that?

I'm using laravel so the html code is like this:

```
<li>{{ Form::email('email', '', array('placeholder' => 'E-mail', 'autocomplete'=>'off')) }}</li>
<li>{{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'autocomplete'=>'off')) }}</li>
```

and the css for it is this:

```
#email-field{
    background:#fff url(../../img/site/username.png) no-repeat 12px center 
}
#pass-field{
    background:#fff url(../../img/site/icon_password.png) no-repeat 12px center
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#email-field:-webkit-autofill,
#pass-field:-webkit-autofill {
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```