# Change Input background to transparent on autocomplete form

Tags: html, css

i wanted to set the background color to transparent to my input when the browser autocomplete my form, currently looks like the image added, anyone know how to accomplish this?

I've tried this but it set to white and the borders are style with the yellow default, i want the color for the text to be white too.

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You want `white` background not `transparent`?

Comment: yes transparent but this is the example i found, so i need it transparent with white text in the input

Comment: `-webkit-text-fill-color`? and `background-color`? Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Finally i get the result with this piece of code:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: what this: 5000s in background-color

Comment: The transition time that will take to remove the background color

Comment: no flaws. fine working after tested almost 20 solutions in chrome

Comment: it worked for me. And the tip for whom wants to change cursor color is the following:
`caret-color: #fff;`

Answer (score 30):

use this to save your time

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
   -webkit-transition-delay: 9999s;
   transition-delay: 9999s;
}
```

Comment: This is so simple and works perfect! Best solution IMO.

Comment: Not only did this seem to be the only one that worked for me, it's damn short!

Comment: Thank you for being such a good person. autofill is just... you know.

Comment: This one should be the best answer 

Comment: Is transparent by default thanks god!

Answer (score 21):

thanks [martinezjc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3403755/martinezjc) for the idea, but if we leave page opened for some time we will notice backround change

we can eliminate transition using css animation and forwards fill mode to make background color permanent

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-animation: autofill 0s forwards;
    animation: autofill 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes autofill {
    100% {
        background: transparent;
        color: inherit;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
    100% {
        background: transparent;
        color: inherit;
    }
}
```

just replace transparent with your color

Comment: Nice i like this. It's amazing all the crap we have to go through just to change a color.

Comment: This solution is more stable. 1. This won't change color after a time 2. If you try to fill an address with name, address, phone etc then this solutions ROCKS (First solution only prevent color change in changed field).

Comment: perfect! Thanks.

Comment: @CaptainAdmin Note that this solution does not work at all in desktop Safari.

Comment: stopped working on firefox with recent updates ;/

Answer (score 5):

After hours of searching, here is the best code that works jquery and javascript meaning it makes the field transparent as requested

```
     input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-animation: autofill 0s forwards;
    animation: autofill 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes autofill {
    100% {
        background: transparent;
        color: inherit;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
    100% {
        background: transparent;
        color: inherit;
    }
}
```

Perfect good

Answer (score 0):

GOT THE ANSWER GUYS..  :)

```
input,
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) inset !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain what are the advantages of your solution over the others.