# Clear browser saved password through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

So here I've a page to change password, but before that I've `Login page` where user logs in and say he has clicked browser's default functionality `Remember me` or `Save Password` or anything it prompts during login, and saves the password!!

Now when I load my `change password` partial view the textbox say with ID `txtOldPassword` will be filled by default whereas textboxes `txtNewPassword` and `txtConfirmPassword` will be left empty!!

I load my `PartialView` as below and tried to clear the `txtOldPassword` value!!

```
$('.menu').on('click',function(){
     $('#body_data').load('/Home/GetChangePassword',function(){
             $('#txtOldPassword').val(''); //Tried to clear the value here       
     });
});
```

But still the value exists!!! Now, I don't want to disable the browser's default functionality but I just want to remove the password that automatically comes and stores in textbox `txtOldPassword`!!

Comment: All the answers suggesting `autocomplete=off` are good, but I think in some chrome versions, it will still not fix this issue. Last time when I dealt with, I had to put a hidden password field in the form because chrome trys to autofill password in the first password field it encounters in the form. This way the problem can be solved.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css

Comment: @gaurav.. how did that trick do?? putting hidden field and confusing browser seems great though!! :)

Comment: It worked pretty well that time :)

Comment: Can you show how you used that!! @gaurav.. :)

Comment: Just put an `<input type="password" name="whatever" style="display:none" />` just above your current password field... this should do the trick

Comment: Great!! will give a try too!! :) Thanks @gaurav.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using autocomplete="off". Not sure if every browser supports it, though. Add this for the field in change password view.

**Update:**

You can try this.

```
$('#Password').attr("autocomplete", "off");
setTimeout('$("#Password").val("");', 2000);
```

Comment: This I think I need to try once!! I'll let you know asap!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Latest browser which supports html5, that will support `Autocomplete="off"`.
Autocomplete supported in following browsers.

1. Chrome >= 17.0
2. i.e. >= 5.0
3. Firefox >= 4.0
4. safari >= 5.2
5. Opera >= 9.6

Learn more about [**AutoComplete**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

**Upadate**

When AutoComplete is not supported, you can use some workaround like this:

```
<input type="password" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"/>
```

Comment: any idea about old browsers which doesn't support html5??

Comment: and where you are suggesting me to put this?? in `login` page or in `change password` page??

Comment: That's Ok!! but am asking about the approach to be followed in traditional browser which doesn't support html5??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao write it in your input element

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, ideally yeah autoComplete should be in input element of changePassword view, and see my updates for workaround when autoComplete is not supported.Hope this will help!

Comment: yea checking on it!! give me a moment!! :)