# Fields not clear after initial post to page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor, webmatrix-3

I am using a template site from Webmatrix 3.0 that includes a sign in page (among other pages) working primarily with c#, razor, html, and jquery.  I have created a new page where users can register that includes a password field, as well as other text fields.  My issue is, even when I simply have two fields on the cshtml page and nothing else, these fields are filled with data during an initial page request.  This data is old "remember me" data from a previous sign in.

I can either do a get request from another page's form to land on this page, or navigate here from a href link, and the result is the same.  To try to find the issue, I even cut almost all the code from the page leaving simply this:

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="password" />
```

And both fields are populated when I make an initial page request.  I have tried to use things like

```html
value = " something like blank or a single space in here "
```

etc in the html, as well as trying to clear out the fields to no avail with javascript (which I prefer not to since I have had very spotty success with things like onload).  Is there a fairly sure fire way to clear text and password fields for initial page requests?  Edit - I have tried autocomplete=off to no avail as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear browser saved password through jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910678/clear-browser-saved-password-through-jquery)

Comment: Thanks NovaLogic, but I have tried autocomplete=off to no avail as well.

Comment: How about <input type="password" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"/> ?

Comment: NovaLogic - I left the first "readonly" part off since the editor didn't like it, then ran it and received no solution as it were.

Comment: Do not leave it off. Try readonly="readonly"  instead of just readonly to calm the editor down. Since the autocomplete thingy did not work, I am guessing you are on an older browser. What browser are you using?

Comment: That calmed the editor down, and did the trick.  Thank you NovaLogic.  Is there a way for me to accept an answer or the like for this solution?

Comment: And, if it helps anyone I was testing against Firefox 41.0.2 and Opera 33.0.

Comment: No need to accept an answer here, since there is already a similar question asked and answered in another post. People will likely be redirected there. Glad to be of help. :)