# How can I change the color of fonts when the input autofill in Chrome?

Tags: css

I had put the css-code like：

```
input：-webkit-autofill{
  color：white;
}
```

but it didn't work.
I hope somebody can help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css/2416597#2416597

Comment: Thanks.This is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, CSS syntax is incorrect. `input：-webkit-autofill` should be `input:-webkit-autofill`. The weird colon thing with the gap is not recognised by the browser.

Also instead of `color：white;` use `-webkit-text-fill-color: white;`

You might be aware of it, but I'll mention it anyway, this will only work on WebKit browsers.

https://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/31999/