# Prevent Browser Adding Light-Blue Background to Input Elements on Second Visit

Tags: html, css, forms, input, background

When a form is filled out for a 2nd time and the browser recognises the details it adds a light-blue background to the form input elements on a site I'm building (which currently have the background set as transparent to show the dark blue background of the parent section). Image attached.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

It doesn't do it the first time of filling the form in, only if you input the details a second time after submission.

In the attached image I've left the fourth (bottom-right) field blank so you can see how it should look.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using anyway? And how about posting a [reprex] so we can have a look at what's going on?

Comment: Where is your code, can you please update your code in this question so that we can work on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
        //The following works as the text color for the autofill 
        -webkit-text-fill-color: (the text color you want);
        //The following works as a background for the autofill 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px (here I would add the blue bg color you are using) inset; 

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just override the `box-shadow` of the input autofill property as shown in this other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css) like this:

```
    input:-webkit-autofill {
        -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px white inset;
    }

    input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px white inset;
    }
```

I tried it on a dummy html form just now and the above (even without the `text-fill-color` property defined) seems to work fine in removing the blue background.

Answer (score 0):

**1**. You can just disable autocomplete in form at all or in some of input fields you want:

```
<form autocomplete="off">...</form>
```

or

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

**2**. Try to overwrite autofill by own CSS rules

```
@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
  to {
    color: inherit;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

input:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill
{
  -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the pseudo selector `:focus` on your `input` like this to remove the blue outline
`input:focus {
outline: none;
}`

Comment: This isn't what I want. It's the light-blue background colour on the input elements I want to remove.

Also you should never have `outline:none` on your focus property on forms - it creates accessibility issues. You should always have `outline: transparent`.