# can't change background-color of text input

Tags: html, css

Perhaps a stupid question:

Here is a screenshot of my login page with a text-input field where I set the background-color. In the developer tools the background color property shows up as red, but in the page it is still grey. Any ideas on how to change it to red?

[image]

edit: under computed it says:

[image]

edit:
this issue might be related to the chromium browser. On Chrome the background color is red

Comment: Could you check under computed tab.

Comment: added a screenshot of the computed tab

Comment: I am not able to reproduce such a behaviour on my system.

Comment: Please check this out: [Override browser form-filling and input highlighting with HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but it does not seem to work either. even using jquery on document.ready to set the background color does not change the result

Comment: i am not able to reproduce it on chrome either. might be my chromium browser

Comment: Maybe try `background` instead of `background-color` or set `box-shadow` to none.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see

there is `-internal-autofill-selected` in computed tab

These are browser's default styles

Perhaps you should do to override it

```
#id_username,
input#id_username:-internal-autofill-selected {
    background-color: red  !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: i just tried it, but this doesn't seem to work either. it shows up on the computed tab but the outcome is still grey

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this

input:-webkit-autofill {
background-color: transparent;
}

Comment: in the developer tools this shows up as crossed out, even if I add !important