# Removing input field active selection highlight

Tags: html, css

I am trying to disable selection highlighting for input fields using CSS.

```css
input[type="email"]::selection { background: transparent }
```

[image: fault image]

Comment: Please attach your code snippet here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles that you're talking about are due to AutoComplete.

[image: autocomplete]

To change them in Chrome, you can use the following CSS:

```css
/* Change Autocomplete styles in Chrome*/
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

More details: [Change Autocomplete Styles in WebKit Browsers](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/)

I am not sure if this is possible in non-WebKit / non-Blink browsers. But this would be a good next step: [Override browser form-filling and input highlighting with HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2338102).

Comment: This is working for me`input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-background-color:transparent;
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}`

Comment: @ravindu Thanks, hope my answer helped. 

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To

just added the style :

```
.input-text:focus{outline:none;}
```

I hope this code will be useful for you.

Thank you.

Comment: yes. I try this before. but not working. Thank for you.